# How to get a country code from a locale code

Tags: locale, country

I have these locales "en", "fr", "es", "ar" and so on, and I want to display a flag representing each locale

I tried using but it returns a list of countries instead of the "main" one

The code I tried

```js
var countryLanguage = require("country-language")

countryLanguage.getLanguage('en', function (err, language) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    var countriesSpeakingEN = language.countries;
    console.log(countriesSpeakingEN);
  }
});
```

You can run it on [RunKit](https://runkit.com/unlocomqx/60da532b489cae001ab8dcba)

Is there another way to map locales to the main country speaking that language?

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2472/how-to-graphically-represent-a-language and more strongly http://www.flagsarenotlanguages.com/blog/why-flags-do-not-represent-language/ https://wplang.org/never-use-flags-language-selection/

Comment: Thank you, I'll just go with [En], [Fr] for now. Shopify should've went with en_US, fr_FR and so on..